# Get cellular carrier's name from windows phone 10

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am currently developing UWP application that I need to get the celullar carrier's name. I saw posts about it for windows phone 8 and 8.1. They use:

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator;
```

But it is depricated now.

Here is what I want for better clarification:

[image]

Does anyone knows how to make it work for windows phone 10?
All the help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not so sure but I think you need to have access to [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241148) to be able to get those details.

Comment: I checked it but I could not found what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [PhoneLine.NetworkName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn878249.aspx) to get the name of the current network that is being used by the phone line.

To use the Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls namespace, we need add the reference like the following image:

[image]

The telephony options and information classes use the CallsPhoneContract. In order to use these classes, you will need to declare the phoneCall capability in your manifest like the following image.

[image]

For example:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PhoneCallStore phoneCallStore = await PhoneCallManager.RequestStoreAsync();
    Guid lineId = await phoneCallStore.GetDefaultLineAsync();
    PhoneLine line = await PhoneLine.FromIdAsync(lineId);
    var currentOperatorName = line.NetworkName;
}
```

An example that demonstrates how to use much of the functionality of the Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls API can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall).

Answer (score 0):

The UWP does not provide built-in api's for things like Mobile Network and Carrier related information, so MNC, MCC, carrier name etc are not possible to get afaik.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation thing might help you. I'm not sure, but it stands to reason that some of that information might be hidden there.

[Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.aspx)

Javascript:

```
var networkInformation = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation;
```

C#

```
public static class NetworkInformation
```

C++

```
public ref class NetworkInformation abstract sealed
```

And you might need to go into one of the submethods provided by this class. Maybe [getConnectionProfiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles.aspx) will do what you want